# Internet browser using PySide: find id/tag of a selected element

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

Consider that I make a browser(Webkit) using PySide. I browse a few pages and use a combination like Ctrl+Click to select an element in some page, like a heading. The program must print the id/xpath or other tag properties of the clicked element. How do I proceed?

Comment: (1) Read the relevant documentation. (2) Start writing code. (3) If you encounter a **specific** problem that you can't solve, try [asking a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible, as from the docs, I couldn't find anything related. Anyway, I'll try it and update my status. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. But my crudely-made point was that your question is far too broad to deal with in a single answer. There are at least three big parts (create a browser, select page elements with the mouse, extract html tag attributes), each of which is in itself possibly too broad for a single question. As for documentation: take a look at [QWebView](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) and [QWebHitTestResult](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebhittestresult.html).

Comment: Thank you, I've made the browser, now implementing the rest.